# In the main function, how to print the value (x,y) from the def __str__?

Tags: python, string

for example

```
def __str__ (self):
    return (x,y)

def main():
```

how do u print the value of x and y from the def **str**(self): function

Would really appreciate it thanks!!!

Comment: is this part of a class?

Comment: yes..this is part of class

Comment: might be worth posting the class code

Answer (score 0):

That code doesn't make sense, so I'm extrapolating.

I'm assuming you have some class like so:

```
class Foobar(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __str__(self):
        return str((x,y))

def main():
    foobar = Foobar(1,2)

main()
```

In this case, you COULD use string manipulation to handle it.

```
x_value, y_value = map(str.strip("()"), str(foobar).split(','))
```

But that's uglier than sin. Why not just reference the values directly?

```
x_value, y_value = foobar.x, foobar.y
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the example in Adam's answer:

```
class Foobar(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __str__(self):
        return '({foo.x}, {foo.y})'.format(foo=self)
```

Would result in:

```
foo = Foobar(2, 3)
print(foo)
'(2, 3)'
```